# How to Enable both Social Login and Active Directory Login for Wordpress

Tags: active-directory, wordpress, social-networking

I have a wordpress site using **Social Login** plugin for visitors from outside my organization and I want to enable the **Active Directory Login** for visitors/editors from inside my organization.

Can the [Social Login Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/oa-social-login/) and [Active Directory Login Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/active-directory-integration/) work side by side to enable these 2 methods at the same time?

What kind of tweaks or what kind of code should I put in place to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress social login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-social-login) plugin will allow you to login both way.

no tweaks needed: some easy steps to follow easy installation:

As admistration, goto 'Plugins' then Click on 'Add New',
 Search for 'WordPress Social Login' then Click on 'Install Now',
 Wait for it to download, Unpack and to install,
 Activate the plugin by Clicking on 'Activate Plugin'
 Goto the Settings > WP Social Login to get started.

[Here](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/wsl/overview.html) is full [documentation](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/wsl/overview.html) of the plugin. make sure your system has desired configuarion.

Comment: It does NOT support AD authentication. I need both AD + Social authentications.